# django, python and link encryption

Tags: python, django, encryption

I need to arrange some kind of encrpytion for generating user specific links. Users will be clicking this link and at some other view, related link with the crypted string will be decrypted and result will be returned.

For this, I need some kind of encryption function that consumes a number(or a string) that is the primary key of my selected item that is bound to the user account, also consuming some kind of seed and generating encryption code that will be decrypted at some other page.

so something like this

```
my_items_pk = 36 #primary key of an item
seed = "rsdjk324j23423j4j2" #some string for crypting
encrypted_string = encrypt(my_items_pk,seed)
#generates some crypted string such as "dsaj2j213jasas452k41k"
and at another page:
decrypt_input = encrypt(decypt,seed)
print decrypt_input
#gives 36
```

I want my "seed" to be some kind of primary variable (not some class) for this purpose (ie some number or string).

How can I achieve this under python and django ?

Comment: Why don't you just use the `session` for this?

Comment: I think you mean checking user auth, yes I will indeed user them but also I also don't want to show item pks to the users and instead crypt them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are no encryption algorithms, per se, built in to Python.  However, you might want to look at the [Python Cryptography Toolkit](http://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/) (PyCrypt).  I've only tinkered with it, but it's referenced in Python's documentation on [cryptographic services](http://docs.python.org/library/crypto.html).  Here's an example of how you could encrypt a string with AES using PyCrypt:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from urllib import quote

# Note that for AES the key length must be either 16, 24, or 32 bytes
encryption_obj = AES.new('abcdefghijklmnop')
plain = "Testing"

# The plaintext must be a multiple of 16 bytes (for AES), so here we pad it
# with spaces if necessary.
mismatch = len(plain) % 16
if mismatch != 0:
  padding = (16 - mismatch) * ' '
  plain += padding

ciph = encryption_obj.encrypt(plain)

# Finally, to make the encrypted string safe to use in a URL we quote it
quoted_ciph = quote(ciph)
```

You would then make this part of your URL, perhaps as part of a GET request.

To decrypt, just reverse the process; assuming that `encryption_obj` is created as above, and that you've retrieved the relevant part of the URL, this would do it:

```
from urllib import unquote

# We've already created encryption_object as shown above

ciph = unquote(quoted_ciph)
plain = encryption_obj.decrypt(ciph)
```

You also might consider a different approach: one simple method would be to hash the primary key (with a salt, if you wish) and store the hash and pk in your database.  Give the user the hash as part of their link, and when they return and present the hash, look up the corresponding pk and return the appropriate object.  (If you want to go this route, check out the built-in library [hashlib](http://docs.python.org/library/hashlib.html#module-hashlib).)

As an example, you'd have something like this defined in models.py:

```
class Pk_lookup(models.Model):
  # since we're using sha256, set the max_length of this field to 32
  hashed_pk = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=32)
  key = models.IntegerField()
```

And you'd generate the hash in a view using something like the following:

```
import hashlib
import Pk_lookup

hash = hashlib.sha256()
hash.update(str(pk)) # pk has been defined previously
pk_digest = hash.digest()

lookup = Pk_lookup(hashed_pk=pk_digest,key=pk)
lookup.save()
```

Note that you'd have to quote this version as well; if you prefer, you can use `hexdigest()` instead of `digest` (you wouldn't have to quote the resulting string), but you'll have to adjust the length of the field to 64.

Comment: I tried your method and add the quoted string to url. But django failed. The details can be seen at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685139/django-cant-have-quoted-characters-in-urls

Answer (score 0):

Django has features for this now.  See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signing/

Quoting that page:

"Django provides both a low-level API for signing values and a high-level API for setting and reading signed cookies, one of the most common uses of signing in Web applications.

You may also find signing useful for the following:

- Generating “recover my account” URLs for sending to users who have lost their password.
- Ensuring data stored in hidden form fields has not been tampered with.
- Generating one-time secret URLs for allowing temporary access to a protected resource, for - example a downloadable file that a user has paid for."