# Django can't have quoted characters in urls?

Tags: python, django

I'm following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2291176/django-python-and-link-encryption) and adopt the code by peppergrower. But when I add the encrypted and quoted characters to the url and try access this url, Django failed with the following errors:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line
>   283, in run
>       self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
>
> File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\handlers.py",
>   line 68, in **call**
>       return self.application(environ, start_response)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py",
>   line 264, in **call**
>       logger.warning('Bad Request (UnicodeDecodeError): %s' % request.path,
>
> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'request' referenced before
>   assignment

A sample url of such kind is http://localhost:8000/customer/unsubscribe/%F1%CDE%A2%9DL%BF%21W%60%FF%04%D2%D2%3B%B1%FB%C9%8Ff%89%06O%FFY%E2_%16%9BnPM/. I notice that as long as % appears in the url, Django would throw above exceptions. It didn't make much sense since the quoted characters already have zero unicodes.

I'm using Django 1.3.1

Comment: A localhost URI isn't going to do us any good...we don't have the same service running on our machines as you do.  Could you instead provide code?

Comment: That actually looks like a bug in Django's error handling, no?  There shouldn't be `UnboundLocalError` in core Django code like that.

Comment: Yes, dkamins, it indeed is a bug. The real error is django can't handle % in the url as it's part of quoted unicode. But when the error is raised, UnboundLocalError happens. Anyway, it's just frustrating that quoted unicode should work fine as django doc says but actually it doesn't.

Comment: @GeorgiePorgie what do you mean by "quoted unicode"? I just put the % example above in my URL and I get no errors. For more info take a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/unicode/#uri-and-iri-handling

Comment: @GeorgiePorgie I stand corrected. It just looked as though no errors were happening when I tested it. I got a 400 Bad Request error. I'm curious to learn more about this issue.

Comment: @mkelley33: The thread referenced in my thread encrypts and quotes the encrypted text. Such encrypted and quoted text usually has % in it if it is a unicode. But somehow Django can't handle this kind of url with quoted unicode, contrary to what its doc says.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few Django tickets relevant to this issue https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16541 and https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/5738. In particular [Malcolm's comment](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/5738#comment:10) on #5738 given in part below:

> The problem is that although UTF-8 is strongly recommended as the
>   encoding for non-ASCII data, it's not actually codified in any spec
>   until quite recently (RFC 2396 leaves things wide open, for example).
>   Only in RFC 3986 were things made clear for IRI to URI encoding.
>
> In the interim, systems were deployed that spit out non-UTF-8 encoded
>   URIs.
>
> So I'm going to commit a change that passes back a 400 response for
>   malformed input (non-UTF-8) but also makes it easier to override the
>   request class, so if somebody is dealing with a legacy system, they
>   can subclass WSGIRequestor or ModPythonRequest to handle decoding the
>   URI however they need to.

Comment: In my case, the unicode is "quoted" to become ascii only text which should be safe in the url. I've seen a lot of website with this kind of "quoted" url. Django captures the url and "unquote" it automatically (it seems to me) but it can't handle it properly.

Comment: If I'm reading the comment correctly it's saying that it can't handle if they aren't UTF-8.

Comment: It seems to be the case. If I have unicode (not the quoted one) directly in url, django seems to think it's fine.